# Using TCP protocol for NFS mount points on linux servers

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs

I'm trying to use TCP protocol for better performance for NFS mounts but currently `/proc/mounts` says its using TCP protocol? does that mean NFS is already using TCP by default?

nfs v3:

> fin028b-nfs.zeus.ghsewn.com:/vol/NFS_Test_Vol/test_share /mnt/test2 nfs rw,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,soft,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,addr=fin028b-nfs.zeus.ghsewn.com 0 0

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat Enterprise Linux [defaults to using TCP](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-nfs.html) to transport NFS.

> TCP is the default transport protocol for NFS version 2 and 3 under Red Hat Enterprise Linux. UDP can be used for compatibility purposes as needed, but is not recommended for wide usage. NFSv4 requires TCP.